# Confirmation email to new user on submitting form via a Profile

Tags: wordpress, profile, email, confirmation

I'm new to CiviCRM on Wordpress and need your help...I've created a sign up profile where a user can enter their contact information....I need to send a conformation email to the user as soon as he submits the form...Is there any way i can do it??

Comment: Hi there, 

You will need to Enable the Double Opt-In for profiles which use the add to group or groups field if that is what your after. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/profiles/#add-new-contacts-to-a-group

Comment: @SeamusLee I think you could add that as an answer

Comment: Yes, That solves my problem. Thanks for the response Seamus:)